# Extracting Text from PDF according to size or color in iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, pdf-parsing

I have some PDF Files with similar layout.

For example, their introduction parts have same font color and size.

I want to extract introduction parts from these PDF Files with using this text property information but i could'nt find any method.

For example, i will give a parameter like #333333, and it returns text from PDF only in #333333 color. Is it possible?

I use iText library.

Thanks..

Comment: I think iText is not the right tool for this task. iText has very limited support for page content parsing.

Comment: Can you suggest any other tool you know? Maybe I can change my library because I will work on content parsing generally

Comment: I changed my library with Apache's PDFBOX. I cannot find a solution for my question in pdfbox too, but it parses text content more clearly according to iText.